# Generalized Runge-Kutta Method

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-derivative, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to understand analytical theory of RK method. I am following the book **A first course in Numerical Analysis by Ralston and Rabinowitz(2nd Edition) Page 225**.

We start with the solution of $\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} = f(x,y)$ to be $y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{m}(w_{i}k_{i})$ where $k_{i} = h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{i}h_{n}, y_{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}k_{j})$.

I have derived upto

\begin{align}
y_{n+1}-y_{n} &= \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty}(h_{n})^{t}\frac{y_{n}^{(t)}}{t!}= \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty}h_{n}^{t+1}\cdot \frac{(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} +f\frac{\partial }{\partial y})^{t}}{(t+1)!}\cdot f(x_{n},y_{n})\\
              &=\bigg[hf + \frac{h^{2}}{2!}Df + \frac{h^{3}}{3!}\bigg(D^{2}f+f_{y}Df\bigg)+ \frac{h^{4}}{4!}\bigg(D^{3}f + f_{y}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{2}Df + 3DfDf_{y}\bigg) \\
&+ \frac{h^{5}}{5!}\bigg(D^{4}f+6DfD^{2}f_{y} + f_{y}^{2}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{3}Df+ 3f_{yy}(Df)^{2} + f_{y}D^{3}f + 7f_{y}DfDf_{y}\bigg)\bigg] + O(h^{6})
\end{align}

Also

\begin{align}
k_{i} &= h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{i}h_{n}, y_{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}k_{j})\\
   &= h_{n}f\bigg[x_{n}+\alpha_{4}h_{n}, y_{n}+(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij})h_{n}f_{n} + \bigg(\sum_{j=2}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\bigg)\bigg] \\
   &= h_{n}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{i}+\sum_{j=2}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t}}{t!}f(x_{n},y_{n})
\end{align} where $$D_{i} = \alpha_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sum (\beta_{ij})f_{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

Now i have to find $k_{i}$ for $i = 1,2,3,4$

Prove that,

\begin{align*}
  \omega_{1} + \omega_{2} + \omega_{3} + \omega_{4} &= 1\\
  \omega_{2}\alpha_{2} + \omega_{3}\alpha_{3} + \omega_{4}\alpha_{4} &= \frac{1}{2}\\
  \omega_{2}\alpha_{2}^{2} + \omega_{3}\alpha_{3}^{2} + \omega_{4}\alpha_{4}^{2} &= \frac{1}{3}\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}\alpha_{2} + \omega_{4}\bigg(\beta_{42}\alpha_{2} + 
  \beta_{43}\alpha_{3}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{6}\\
  \omega_{2}\alpha_{2}^{3} + 
  \omega_{3}\alpha_{3}^{3} + 
  \omega_{4}\alpha_{4}^{3} &= \frac{1}{4}\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}\alpha_{2}^{2} + \omega_{4}\bigg(\beta_{42}\alpha_{2}^{2} +
  \beta_{43}\alpha_{3}^{2}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{12}\\
  \omega_{4}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}\alpha_{2} &= \frac{1}{24}\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}\alpha_{2}\alpha_{3}+ 
  \omega_{4}\bigg(\beta_{42}\alpha_{2}\alpha_{4} + 
  \beta_{43}\alpha_{3}\alpha_{4}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{8}
 \end{align*}

Edit: I finally got the proof done.

Comment: ‍‍‍

Comment: I am feeling dizzy as well. I am starting to understand how brilliant and patient Runge, Kutta, ralston and rabinowitz were.

Comment: Truly brilliant. I admire your sticktoitiveness in actually typing all of this out 

Comment: You can simplify the calculus without losing generality by considering autonomous systems (and demand consistency of order 0, that is, $α_i=\sum_jβ_{ij}$). Then switch over to Butcher trees for a slightly more compact symbolism for the $f$-derivative constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is about doing linear approximation of slopes calculated within $x_{n+1} - x_{n} = h_{n}$ such that the $y_{n+1}$ values closely corresponds to the Taylor series approximation at that point thus overcoming the error caused by generic euler method.

The solution of

\begin{equation}\label{E3}
 \begin{split}
  \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} &= f(x,y)
   \end{split}
\end{equation}

is to be defined by

\begin{equation}\label{E1}
 \begin{split}
  y_{n+1} & = y_{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{m}(w_{i}k_{i}) \\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

where $w_{i}$ are weighted values of slopes and

\begin{equation}\label{E2}
 \begin{split}
  k_{i} &= h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{i}h_{n}, y_{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}k_{j})
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

are slope values.

We will have to find the values of $\alpha_{i}$, $\beta_{ij}$, $h_{n}$ and $w_{i}$ to compute the solution. Initially $\alpha_{1} = 0, h_{n}=x_{n+1}-x_{n}$

Expanding $F(x_{n+1})$,

\begin{align*}
 F(x_{n+1}) &= F(x_{n}) + F^{\prime}(x_{n})(x_{n+1}-x_{n}) + \frac{F^{\prime\prime}(x_{n})(x_{n+1}-x_{n})^{2}}{2!}...........\\
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  y_{n+1}-y_{n} &= F(x_{n+1})-F(x_{n}) \\
  &= (x_{n+1}-x_{n})F^{\prime}(x_{n}) + (x_{n+1}-x_{n})^{2} \frac{F^{\prime\prime}(x_{n})}{2!} + ....... \\
  &= h_{n}F^{\prime}(x_{n}) + (h_{n})^{2}\frac{F^{\prime\prime}(x_{n})}{2!} + .......... (h_{n} = x_{n+1} - x_{n})\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{E5}
 \begin{split}
  y_{n+1}-y_{n} &= \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty}(h_{n})^{t}\frac{y_{n}^{(t)}}{t!}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{df}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =&  (\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial y})f \text{...... where }\\
    & (\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}) \text{ is a type of differential operator}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Again,

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d^{2}f}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx^{2}}}} &= \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)\\ 
   &= \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}} + f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} + f^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}+f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
   &=  (\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial y})^{2}f\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

and,

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
   \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d^{3}f}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx^{3}}}} &= \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}\\ 
   &= \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}+f\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}\\
   &= \bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+f\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)^{3}f\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

In addition, $y_{n}^{\prime} = f(x_{n},y_{n}),$ Assuming differentiability,

\begin{equation}\label{E4}
 \begin{split}
    y_{n}^{t} &= \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}^{t-1}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}^{t-1}} \left\{y^{\prime}(x_{n},y_{n})\right\}\\ 
    &= \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}^{t-1}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}^{t-1}} f(x,y)_{|_{x_{n},y_{n}}}\\
    &= \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t-1}f(x_{n},y_{n})\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

Defining

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  D &= \bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + {\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)\Big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} = \bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)....f_{n} = f(x,y)\vert_{x_{n}, y_{n}}  \text{ is a constant}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  D^{2} &= \bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)\\
  &= \Big(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 2f_{n}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x \partial y} + f_{n}^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\Big)\Big\vert_{n}
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d^{2}f}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx^{2}}}}\Big\vert_{n} &= \Big(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}} + 2f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} + f^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big)\Big\vert_{n}\\
  &= \Big(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}} + 2f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} + f^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}\Big)\Big\vert_{n} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{dy}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx}}}\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}\bigg)\Big\vert_{n}\\
  &=D^{2}f\Big\vert_{n}+f_{y}Df\Big\vert_{n}\\                   
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d^{3}f}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx^{3}}}} =& {\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x^{3}} + 3f\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x^{2}\partial y} + 3f^{2}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x \partial y^{2}} + f^{3}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial y^{3}}} + {\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}+ 2f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} + f^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^{2}}\Big)} \\
        +& {\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big)^{2}\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big)} + 3\Big(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}\Big\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big\} + f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}\Big\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big\}\Big)\\
  =& {\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x^{3}} + 3f\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x^{2}\partial y} + 3f^{2}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x \partial y^{2}} + f^{3}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial y^{3}}} \\
+&{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}} + 2f\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} + f^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^{2}}\Big)} + {\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big)^{2}\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big)}\\
  +& 3\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big)\Big(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  D^{3} =& \bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}} + 2f_{n}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} + f_{n}^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\\
  =& \frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x^{3}} + 3f_{n}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x^{2}\partial y} + 3f_{n}^{2}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial x\partial y^{2}} + f_{n}^{3}\frac{\partial^{3}f}{\partial y^{3}}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d^{3}f}}}{\mathop{\mathrm{dx^{3}}}}\Big\vert_{n} = D^{3}f + f_{y}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{2}Df + 3DfDf_{y}\Big\vert_{n}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation}\label{E6}
 \begin{split}
   y_{n+1}-y_{n} &= \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty}(h_{n})^{t}\frac{y_{n}^{(t)}}{t!}\\
   &= \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty}h_{n}^{t+1}\cdot \frac{(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} +f\frac{\partial }{\partial y})^{t}}{(t+1)!}\cdot f(x_{n},y_{n})\\
   &=\bigg[hf + \frac{h^{2}}{2!}Df + \frac{h^{3}}{3!}\bigg(D^{2}f+f_{y}Df\bigg)  \\
   & + \frac{h^{4}}{4!}\bigg(D^{3}f + f_{y}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{2}Df + 3DfDf_{y}\bigg) \\
   & + \frac{h^{5}}{5!}\bigg(D^{4}f+6DfD^{2}f_{y} + f_{y}^{2}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{3}Df \\
   & + 3f_{yy}(Df)^{2} + f_{y}D^{3}f + 7f_{y}DfDf_{y}\bigg)\bigg] + O(h^{6})\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
 k_{i} &= h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{i}h_{n}, y_{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}k_{j}) &   &   &   &    &     & &  &  &\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 k_{1} &= h_{n}f(x_{n}, y_{n}) = h_{n}f_{n}\\ 
 k_{2} &= h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{2}h_{n}, y_{n}+\beta_{21}k_{1})\\
 k_{3} &= h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{3}h_{n}, y_{n} + \beta_{31}k_{1} + \beta_{32}k_{2})\\
 &= h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{3}h_{n}, y_{n} + \beta_{31}k_{1} + \beta_{32}k_{1} + \beta_{32}k_{2} - \beta_{32}k_{1})\\
 &= h_{n}f(x_{n} + \alpha_{4}h_{n}, y_{n} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1}\beta_{4j}h_{n}f_{n} + \beta_{42}(k_{2} - h_{n}f_{n}) + \beta_{43}(k_{3}-h_{n}f_{n}))\\
 &= h_{n}f(x_{n} + \alpha_{4}h_{n}, y_{n} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1}\beta_{4j}h_{n}f_{n} + \sum_{j=2}^{i-1}\beta_{4j}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n}))
\end{align*}

Let  $$D_{i} = \alpha_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1} (\beta_{ij})f_{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

\begin{align*}
 k_{i} &= h_{n}f\bigg[x_{n}+\alpha_{i}h_{n}, y_{n}+(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij})h_{n}f_{n} + \bigg(\sum_{j=2}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\bigg)\bigg] &    &     &     &   &  &   &    &   &\\
 &= h_{n}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{i}+\sum_{j=2}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t}}{t!}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} &    &     &  &  &    &    &   &     &\\
\end{align*}

Since $\alpha_{1} = 0$
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    k_{1} =& h_{n}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
    k_{2} =& h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{2}h_{n},y_{n}+\beta_{21}k_{1})=h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{2}h_{n},y_{n}+\beta_{21}h_{n}f_{n})\\
    =& h_{n} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{h_{n}^{t}D_{2}^{t}}{t!}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\     
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  k_{3} = & h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{3}h_{n},y_{n}+\beta_{31}k_{1}+\beta_{32}k_{2})\\
  =& h_{n}f\bigg[x_{n}+\alpha_{3}h_{n},y_{n}+h_{n}f_{n}(\beta_{31}+\beta_{32})+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\bigg]\\
  =& h_{n}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t}}{t!}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\ 
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}      
  k_{4} =& h_{n}f(x_{n}+\alpha_{4}h_{n},y_{n}+\beta_{41}k_{1}+\beta_{42}k_{2}+\beta_{43}k_{3})\\
   =& h_{n}f\bigg[x_{n}+\alpha_{2}h_{n},y_{n}+h_{n}f_{n}(\beta_{41}+\beta_{42}+\beta_{43})+\beta_{41}(k_{1}-h_{n}f_{n})+\beta_{42}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\\
  & +\beta_{43}(k_{3}-h_{n}f_{n})\bigg]\\
  =& h_{n}f\bigg[x_{n}+\alpha_{4}h_{n}, y_{n}+(\sum_{j=1}^{3}\beta_{4j})h_{n}f_{n} + (\sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j})(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\bigg]\\
  =& h_{n}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{4}+\sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t}}{t!}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

$$f(x_{n}+\alpha_{i}h_{n}, y_{n}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}k_{j}) = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{h_{n}^{t}D^{t}_{i}}{t!}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}$$

\begin{align*}
  k_{1} =& h_{n}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\ 
  =& h_{n}f_{n} \\
  k_{2} =& h_{n}\bigg(\frac{h_{n}^{0}D_{2}^{0}}{0!}f(x,y) + \frac{h_{n}^{1}D_{2}^{1}}{1!}f(x,y) + \frac{h_{n}^{2}D_{2}^{2}}{2!}f(x,y) + \frac{h_{n}^{3}D_{2}^{3}}{3!}f(x,y) + \frac{h_{n}^{4}D_{2}^{4}}{4!}f(x,y)\bigg)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\ 
  +& O(h_{n}^{6})\\
  =& h_{n}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{h_{n}^{2}}{1!}D_{2}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{h_{n}^{3}}{2!}D_{2}^{2}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{h_{n}^{4}}{3!}D_{2}^{3}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\ 
  +& \frac{h_{n}^{5}}{4!}D_{2}^{4}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + O(h_{n}^{6})\\
\end{align*}

We will express  $D_{i}^{t}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} = D_{i}^{t}f_{n}$. Which means the differentiation is already done than the expression is evaluated at $(x= x_{n}, y=y_{n})$ and represents a constant value

\begin{align*}
   (k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n}) \text{ }=&  h_{n}^{2}D_{2}f_{n} + \frac{h^{3}}{2!}D_{2}^{2}f_{n} + \frac{h_{n}^{4}}{3!}D_{2}^{3}f_{n} + \frac{h_{n}^{5}}{4!}D_{2}^{4}f_{n} + O(h^{6})\\
\end{align*}

The evaluated $(k_{2} - h_{n}f_{n})$ expression is constant

\begin{align*}
   &h_{n}\bigg[h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]^{2}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
            &= h\bigg[hD_{3} + \beta_{32}\bigg(\frac{h^{2}}{1!}D_{2}f_{n} + \frac{h^{3}}{2!}D_{2}^{2}f_{n} + \frac{h^{4}}{3!}D_{2}^{3}f_{n} + \frac{h^{5}}{4!}D_{2}^{4}f_{n}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]^{2}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
   &= h_{n}^{3}D_{3}^{2}f_{n} + 2h_{n}^{4}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}} + h_{n}^{5}\beta_{32}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}} + h_{n}^{5}\beta_{32}^{2}(D_{2}f_{n})^{2}f_{yy_{|_{n}}}  
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  &h_{n}\bigg[h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]^{3}f \\
  &= \bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg[h_{n}\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}\bigg]f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + O(h_{n}^{6})\\
  &= h_{n}^{4}D_{3}^{3}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + 2h^{5}\beta_{32}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h^{5}\beta_{32}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + O(h^{6})\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  h_{n}\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{3}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} &= h_{n}^{4}D_{3}^{3}f_{n} + 3h_{n}^{5}\beta_{32}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}^{2}f_{y_{|_{n}}} + O(h^{6}) 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  h_{n}\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{4}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} &= \bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)\\
  &\bigg[h_{n}\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{3}f(x,y)\bigg]\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
  &+ O(h_{n}^{6})\\
  &=\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}\bigg)\bigg[h_{n}^{4}D_{3}^{3}f(x,y)\bigg]\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + O(h_{n}^{6})\\
  &= h_{n}^{5}D_{3}^{4}f_{n} + O(h_{n}^{6})
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
    k_{3} &= h_{n}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t}}{t!}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
    &= h_{n}f_{n} + h_{n}^{2}D_{3}f_{n} + h_{n}\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})f_{y_{|_{n}}} + h_{n}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{2}}{2!}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
    &+ h_{n}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{3}}{3!}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}  +h_{n}\frac{\bigg(hD_{3}+\beta_{32}(k_{2}-hf)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{4}}{4!}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + O(h^{6}) \\
    &= h_{n}f_{n} + h_{n}^{2}D_{3}f_{n} + h_{n}^{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{3}^{2}f_{n} + \beta_{32}f_{y_{|_{n}}}D_{2}f_{n}\bigg) + h_{n}^{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}D_{3}^{3}f_{n} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}f_{y_{|_{n}}}D_{2}^{2}f_{n} + \beta_{32}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}}\bigg) \\
    &+ h^{5}\bigg(\frac{1}{24}D^{4}_{3}f_{n} + \frac{1}{6}\beta_{32}f_{y_{|_{n}}}D_{2}^{3}f_{n} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}^{2}(D_{2}f_{n})^{2}f_{yy_{|_{n}}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}^{2}f_{y_{|_{n}}}\bigg) + O(h_{n}^{6})
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
  k_{3} - h_{n}f_{n} &= h_{n}^{2}D_{3}f_{n} + h_{n}^{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{3}^{2}f_{n} + \beta_{32}f_{y_{|_{n}}}D_{2}f_{n}\bigg) + h_{n}^{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}D_{3}^{3}f_{n} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}f_{y_{|_{n}}}D_{2}^{2}f_{n} + \beta_{32}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}}\bigg)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  &h_{n}\bigg[h_{n}D_{4} + \sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j}(k_{j} - h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
  &= h_{n}^{2}D_{4}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}\beta_{42}(k_{2}-h_{n}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}\beta_{43}(k_{3}-h_{n}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
  &= h_{n}^{2}D_{4}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}^{3}\bigg(\beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg) \\
  &+ h_{n}^{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}(D_{3}^{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y_{|_{n}}}(D_{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg)\\
  &+h_{n}^{5}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}\beta_{42}(D_{2}^{3}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} +\frac{1}{6}\beta_{43}(D_{3}^{3}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y_{|_{n}}}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
  &+ \beta_{32}\beta_{43}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  & h_{n}\bigg[h_{n}D_{4} + \sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j}(k_{j} - h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]^{2}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
  &=  h_{n}^{3}D_{4}^{2}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}^{4}\bigg(2\beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + 2\beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg) \\
  &+h_{n}^{5}\bigg(\beta_{42}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{43}(D_{3}^{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + 2\beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y_{|_{n}}}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
  &+ \beta_{42}^{2}(D_{2}f_{n})^{2}f_{yy}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{43}^{2}(D_{3}f_{n})^{2}f_{yy}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + 2\beta_{42}\beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})(D_{2}f_{n})f_{yy}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  &h_{n}\bigg[h_{n}D_{4} + \sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j}(k_{j} - h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]^{3}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
  &= h_{n}^{4}D_{4}^{3}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}^{5}\bigg(2\beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + 2\beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
  &+\beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg)\\
  &= h_{n}^{4}D_{4}^{3}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}+h_{n}^{5}\bigg(3\beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + 3\beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  &h_{n}\bigg[h_{n}D_{4} + \sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j}(k_{j} - h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg]^{4}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
  &= h_{n}^{5}D_{4}^{4}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + O(h_{n}^{6})
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
   k_{4} &= h_{n}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg(h_{n}D_{4}+\sum_{j=2}^{3}\beta_{4j}(k_{j}-h_{n}f_{n})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^{t}}{t!}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
   &= h_{n}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}^{2}D_{4}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + h_{n}^{3}\bigg[\frac{1}{2}D_{4}^{2}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
   &+ \beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg] + h_{n}^{4}\bigg[\frac{1}{6}D_{4}^{3}f(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}(D_{3}^{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
   &+ \beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y_{|_{n}}}(D_{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg]\\
   &+h_{n}^{5}\bigg[\frac{1}{24}D_{4}^{4}f(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{6}\beta_{42}(D_{2}^{3}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} +\frac{1}{6}\beta_{43}(D_{3}^{3}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y_{|_{n}}}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\\
   &+ \beta_{32}\beta_{43}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{3}f_{y_{|_{n}}}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}(D_{2}^{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}(D_{3}^{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
   &+ \beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y_{|_{n}}}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}f_{y}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}^{2}(D_{2}f_{n})^{2}f_{yy}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}^{2}(D_{3}f_{n})^{2}f_{yy}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} \\
   &+ \beta_{42}\beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})(D_{2}f_{n})f_{yy}(x,y)\bigg\vert_{x=x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}(D_{2}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}(D_{3}f_{n})D_{4}^{2}f_{y}(x,y)\big\vert_{x = x_{n}, y= y_{n}}\bigg]
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
  k_{4} =& hf + h^{2}D_{4}f + h^{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{4}^{2}f + \beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}f + \beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}f\bigg) + h^{4}\bigg[\frac{1}{6}D^{3}_{4}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}^{2}f\\
  +& \beta_{32}\beta_{43}(f_{y})^{2}D_{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}^{2}f + \beta_{42}D_{2}fD_{4}f_{y} + \beta_{43}D_{3}fD_{4}f_{y}\bigg] +  h^{5}\bigg(\frac{1}{24}D_{4}^{4}f + \frac{1}{6}\beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}^{3}f\\
  +&\frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}(f_{y})^{2}D_{2}^{2}f + \beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{2}fD_{3}f_{y} + \frac{1}{6}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}^{3}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}D_{4}f_{y}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}D_{4}f_{y}D_{3}^{2}f\\
  +&\frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}^{2}f_{yy}D_{2}^{2}f + \beta_{42}\beta_{43}f_{yy}D_{2}fD_{3}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}^{2}f_{yy}D_{3}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}D_{2}fD_{4}^{2}f_{y}\\
  +& \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}D_{3}fD_{4}^{2}f_{y} + \beta_{43}\beta_{32}f_{y}D_{2}fD_{4}f_{y}\bigg)\bigg\vert_{n} + O(h^{6})
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  y_{n+1} - y_{n} &= w_{1}k_{1} + w_{2}k_{2} + w_{3}k_{3} + w_{4}k_{4}\\
  &= \bigg[hf + \frac{h^{2}}{2!}Df + \frac{h^{3}}{3!}\bigg(D^{2}f+f_{y}Df\bigg)  + \frac{h^{4}}{4!}\bigg(D^{3}f + f_{y}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{2}Df + 3DfDf_{y}\bigg)\\ 
  &+ \frac{h^{5}}{5!}\bigg(D^{4}f+6DfD^{2}f_{y} + f_{y}^{2}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{3}Df + 3f_{yy}(Df)^{2} + f_{y}D^{3}f + 7f_{y}DfDf_{y}\bigg)\bigg]\\
  &= w_{1}hf + w_{2}\bigg\{hf + \frac{h^{2}}{1!}D_{2}f + \frac{h^{3}}{2!}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{h^{4}}{3!}D_{2}^{3}f + \frac{h^{5}}{4!}D_{2}^{4}f\bigg\}\\ 
  &+ w_{3}\bigg\{hf + h^{2}D_{3}f + h^{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{3}^{2}f + f_{y}\beta_{32}D_{2}f\bigg) + h^{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}D_{3}^{3}f + \frac{1}{2}f_{y}\beta_{32}D_{2}^{2}f + \beta_{32}D_{3}f_{y}D_{2}f\bigg) \\
  &+ h^{5}\bigg(\frac{1}{24}D^{4}_{3}f + \frac{\beta_{32}}{6}f_{y}D_{2}^{3}f + \frac{\beta_{32}^{2}}{2}f_{yy}(D_{2}f)^{2} + \frac{\beta_{32}}{2}D_{3}f_{y}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{\beta_{32}}{2}D_{3}^{2}f_{y}D_{2}f\bigg)\bigg\}\\
  &+ w_{4} \bigg\{hf + h^{2}D_{4}f + h^{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{4}^{2}f + \beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}f + \beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}f\bigg) + h^{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}D^{3}_{4}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}^{2}f\\
  &+ \beta_{32}\beta_{43}(f_{y})^{2}D_{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}^{2}f + \beta_{42}D_{2}fD_{4}f_{y} + \beta_{43}D_{3}fD_{4}f_{y}\bigg) +  h^{5}\bigg(\frac{1}{24}D_{4}^{4}f + \frac{1}{6}\beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}^{3}f\\
  &+\frac{1}{2}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}(f_{y})^{2}D_{2}^{2}f + \beta_{32}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{2}fD_{3}f_{y} + \frac{1}{6}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}^{3}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}D_{4}f_{y}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}D_{4}f_{y}D_{3}^{2}f\\
  &+\frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}^{2}f_{yy}D_{2}^{2}f + \beta_{42}\beta_{43}f_{yy}D_{2}fD_{3}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}^{2}f_{yy}D_{3}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}D_{2}fD_{4}^{2}f_{y}\\
  &+ \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}D_{3}fD_{4}^{2}f_{y} + \beta_{43}\beta_{32}f_{y}D_{2}fD_{4}f_{y}\bigg)\bigg\}    
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  w_{1} + w_{2} + w_{3} + w_{4} &= 1\\
  w_{2}D_{2}f + w_{3}D_{3}f + w_{4}D_{4}f&= \frac{1}{2}Df\\
  \frac{1}{2}w_{2}D_{2}^{2}f + w_{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{3}^{2}f + f_{y}\beta_{32}D_{2}f\bigg) & \\
  + w_{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}D_{4}^{2}f + \beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}f + \beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}f\bigg) &= \frac{1}{3!}\bigg(D^{2}f+f_{y}Df\bigg)\\
  \frac{1}{3!}w_{2}D_{2}^{3}f + w_{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}D_{3}^{3}f + \frac{1}{2}f_{y}\beta_{32}D_{2}^{2}f + \beta_{32}D_{3}f_{y}D_{2}f\bigg) & \\
  +w_{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}D^{3}_{4}f + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{42}f_{y}D_{2}^{2}f+ \beta_{32}\beta_{43}(f_{y})^{2}D_{2}f & \\
  + \frac{1}{2}\beta_{43}f_{y}D_{3}^{2}f + \beta_{42}D_{2}fD_{4}f_{y} + \beta_{43}D_{3}fD_{4}f_{y}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{4!}\bigg(D^{3}f + f_{y}D^{2}f + f_{y}^{2}Df + 3DfDf_{y}\bigg)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \omega_{1} + \omega_{2} + \omega_{3} + \omega_{4} &= 1\\
  \omega_{2}D_{2}f + \omega_{3}D_{3}f + \omega_{4}D_{4}f &= \frac{1}{2}Df\\
  \therefore 
  \frac{1}{2}\omega_{2}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\omega_{3}D_{3}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\omega_{4}D_{2}^{4}&= \frac{1}{6}D^{2}f\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}D_{2}f + \omega_{4}\bigg(\beta_{42}D_{2}f + \beta_{43}D_{3}f\bigg) &= \frac{1}{6}Df\\
  \frac{1}{6}\omega_{2}D_{2}^{3}f + \frac{1}{6}\omega_{3}D_{3}^{3}f + \frac{1}{6}\omega_{4}D_{4}^{3}f &= \frac{1}{24}D^{3}f\\
  \frac{1}{2}\omega_{3}\beta_{32}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\omega_{4}\beta_{42}D_{2}^{2}f + \frac{1}{2}\omega_{4}\beta_{43}D_{3}^{2}f &= \frac{1}{24}D^{2}f\\
  \omega_{4}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}D_{2}f &= \frac{1}{24}Df\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}D_{2}fD_{3}f_{y} + \omega_{4}\beta_{42}D_{2}fD_{4}f_{y} + \omega_{4}\beta_{43}D_{3}fD_{4}f_{y} &= \frac{1}{8}DfDf_{y}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \omega_{1} + \omega_{2} + \omega_{3} + \omega_{4} &= 1\\
  \omega_{2}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}f}{Df}\bigg) + \omega_{3}\bigg(\frac{D_{3}f}{Df}\bigg) + \omega_{4}\bigg(\frac{D_{4}f}{Df}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{2}\\
  \omega_{2}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}^{2}f}{D^{2}f}\bigg) + \omega_{3}\bigg(\frac{D_{3}^{2}f}{D^{2}f}\bigg) + \omega_{4}\bigg(\frac{D_{4}^{2}f}{D^{2}f}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{3}\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}f}{Df}\bigg) + \omega_{4}\bigg\{\beta_{42}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}f}{Df}\bigg) + 
  \beta_{43}\bigg(\frac{D_{3}f}{Df}\bigg)\bigg\} &= \frac{1}{6}\\
  \omega_{2}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}^{3}f}{D^{3}f}\bigg) + 
  \omega_{3}\bigg(\frac{D_{3}^{3}f}{D^{3}f}\bigg) + 
  \omega_{4}\bigg(\frac{D_{4}^{3}f}{D^{3}f}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{4}\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}^{2}f}{D^{2}f}\bigg) + \omega_{4}\bigg\{\beta_{42}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}^{2}f}{D^{2}f}\bigg) +
  \beta_{43}\bigg(\frac{D_{3}^{2}f}{D^{2}f}\bigg)\bigg\} &= \frac{1}{12}\\
  \omega_{4}\beta_{32}\beta_{43}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}f}{Df}\bigg) &= \frac{1}{24}\\
  \omega_{3}\beta_{32}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}f}{Df}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{D_{3}f_{y}}{Df_{y}}\bigg) + 
  \omega_{4}\bigg\{\beta_{42}\bigg(\frac{D_{2}f}{Df}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{D_{4}f_{y}}{Df_{y}}\bigg) + 
  \beta_{43}\bigg(\frac{D_{3}f}{Df}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{D_{4}f_{y}}{Df_{y}}\bigg)\bigg\} &= \frac{1}{8}
\end{align*}

In order to make a general theory that works for all differential equation, the value of $\omega_{i}, \alpha_{i}, \beta_{ij}$ has to be independent of $f(x,y)$.

\begin{align*}
 D &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
 D_{i}&= \alpha_{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\end{align*}

$\frac{D_{i}f}{Df} = \frac{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}$

$\frac{D_{i}f_{y}}{Df_{y}} = \frac{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial y}}$

The only way to make these expressions free of $f(x,y)$ is to let the numerator and denominator cancels each other. That will be only possible when, $$\frac{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\Rightarrow \frac{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \alpha_{i}f_{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\cdot\alpha_{i}$$

$$\frac{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial x} + f_{n}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial y}}\Rightarrow \frac{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial x} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij}f_{n}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial y}}{\alpha_{i}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial x} + \alpha_{i}f_{n}\frac{\partial f_{y}}{\partial y}}\cdot\alpha_{i}$$

$$\therefore \alpha_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\beta_{ij} \text{ and that infers to  } D_{i}=\alpha_{i} D$$

Comment: Had to limit my writing within 30k. Skipped steps.